# Sass compile issues

Tags: css, sass

From the command line, I call `npm run sass`

the script should fire off `node-sass /scss/base.scss /css/style.css -w`.

Instead, I get an **error** `ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/scss/base.scss'`

Things I've tried:

- adding `.` in front of both paths, example `./scss/base.scss`
- removing `./` from the path's
- removed `-w`

  Would **git Desktop** software have anything do to with it?

[image]

Comment: Check the case-sensitivity. You have `Scss` as the directory name, not `scss`.

Comment: Gave that a try and new errors. Thank you for taking a crack at it. I'm baffled. Clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder name is capitalized the sass plugin is looking for scss folder in lowecase.

Comment: I just updated my attempt when changing to lower case. A new error now.

Comment: Replace your command with this one :  
`node-sass /scss/base.scss -o /css/base.css -w`

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for `VSCode called (Sass),` install and create `style.scss` file then you can see a button at the bottom of the `vscode window.` which will auto compile a new file style.css then you can link the `style.css` file to the `HTML` file.